# Numba jit and deferred types

Tags: python, numba

I'm passing numba as signature of my function

```
@numba.jit(numba.types.UniTuple(numba.float64[:, :], 2)(
    numba.float64[:, :], numba.float64[:, :], numba.float64[:, :], 
earth_model_type))
```

where `earth_model_type` is defined as

```
earth_model_type = numba.deferred_type()
earth_model_type.define(em.EarthModel.class_type.instance_type)
```

and it compiles fine, but when I try to call the function I get

> *** TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C), array(float64, 2d, F),
>   instance.jitclass.EarthModel#7fd9c48dd668

The types of the arguments with no-matching definition look to me pretty much the same as my types above. On the other hand, if I don't specify the signature by just using `@numba.jit(nopython=True)`, it works fine and the signature of the function compiled by numba is

```
ipdb> numbed_cowell_propagator_propagate.signatures
```

> [(array(float64, 2d, F), array(float64, 2d, C), array(float64, 2d, F),
>   instance.jitclass.EarthModel#7f81bbc0e780)]

**EDIT**

If I enforce C-order arrays using the way in the [FAQ](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html) I still get an error

> TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64,
>   2d, C), array(float64, 2d, C), array(float64, 2d, C),
>   instance.jitclass.EarthModel#7f6edd8d57b8

I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the deferred type, since if instead of passing the jit class, I pass all the attributes I need from that class (4 `numba.float64`s), it works fine.

What am I doing wrong when I specify the signature?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without understanding exactly how your full code works, I'm not sure why you need to use a deferred type. Typically it is used for jitclasses that contain an instance variable that is of the same type, like a linked list or some other tree of nodes, and therefore needs to be deferred until after the compiler processes the class itself (see the [source](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/10ebb59a40e1e6b3c70c169b186de135fc3e1429/numba/types/misc.py#L427-L431)) The following minimal example works (I can reproduce your error if I use a deferred type):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

spec = [('x', nb.float64)]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class EarthModel:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

earth_model_type = EarthModel.class_type.instance_type

@nb.jit(nb.float64(nb.float64[:, :], nb.float64[:, :], nb.float64[:, :], earth_model_type))
def test(x, y, z, em):
    return em.x
```

and then running it:

```
em = EarthModel(9.9)
x = np.random.normal(size=(3,3))
y = np.random.normal(size=(3,3))
z = np.random.normal(size=(3,3))

res = test(x, y, z, em)
print(res)  # 9.9
```

Comment: I submitted an issue for clarification (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4492) since I'm not sure why the deferred_type does not work, even if you don't necessarily need it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here!! I was using a deferred type because I though that was the way of specifying a class in a signature...but because you mentioned it I tried `em.EarthModel.class_type.instance_type` directly instead, and it works just fine

Comment: No problem. If the answer solved your issue, please select as the correct solution.