# How make a python class jitclass compatible when it contains itself jitclass classes?

Tags: python, class, jit, numba

I'm trying to make a class that could be a part of `jitclass` but has some attribute that are them-self `jitclass` objects.

For example, if I have two class with the decorator `@jitclass`, I would like instanced those in a third class (`combined`).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass
from numba import boolean, int32, float64,uint8

spec = [
    ('type' ,int32),
    ('val' ,float64[:]),
    ('result',float64)]

@jitclass(spec)
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 1
        self.val = np.ones(100)
        self.result = 0.
    def sum(self):
        self.result = np.sum(self.val)

@jitclass(spec)
class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 2
        self.val = np.ones(100)
        self.result = 0.
    def sum(self):
        self.result = np.sum(self.val)



@jitclass(spec)
class Combined:
    def __init__(self):
        self.List = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.List.append(First())
            self.List.append(Second())

    def sum(self):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.List):
            c.sum()
    def getresult(self):
        result = []
        for i, c in enumerate(self.List):
            result.append(c.result)
        return result


C = Combined()
C.sum()
result = C.getresult()
print(result)
```

In that example I get an error because `numba` cannot determine the type of `self.List` which is a combination of the two jitclasses.

How can I make the class `Combined` be `jitclass` compatible?

### Update

It tried something I found elsewhere:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, deferred_type
from numba import boolean, int32, float64,uint8
from numba.typed import List

spec = [
    ('type' ,int32),
    ('val' ,float64[:]),
    ('result',float64)]

@jitclass(spec)
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 1
        self.val = np.ones(100)
        self.result = 0.
    def sum(self):
        self.result = np.sum(self.val)
 

 
spec1 = [('ListA',  List(First.class_type.instance_type, reflected=True))]

@jitclass(spec1)
class Combined:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ListA = [First(),First()] 

    def sum(self):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            c.sum()
    def getresult(self):
        result = []
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            result.append(c.result)
        return result


C = Combined()
C.sum()
result = C.getresult()
print(result)
```

But I get this error

```
List(First.class_type.instance_type)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: did you check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682260/how-to-nest-numba-jitclass)? It is not 100% what you need, but it may help - and it gives some examples.

Comment: This solution work if I instantiate only once the class First, but I would like to have a list of those. I updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

- You can reference other `jitclass`es in a `jitclass` even if you have a list of those. You just need to correct the namespace `numba.typed` -> `numba.types`.
- It's currently (as of numba 0.46) not possible to have heterogeneous lists in `jitclass`es or no-python `numba.jit` functions. So you cannot append both instances of `First` and `Second` in the same list.

### Solving the `numba.typed.List` exception

Your update was almost correct. You need to use `numba.types.List` not `numba.typed.List`. The difference is a bit subtle but the `numba.types` contains types for signatures while the `numba.typed` namespace contains classes that can be instantiated and used in code.

So it will work if you use:

```
spec1 = [('ListA',  nb.types.List(First.class_type.instance_type, reflected=True))]
```

With that change this code:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

spec = [
    ('type', nb.int32),
    ('val', nb.float64[:]),
    ('result', nb.float64)
]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 1
        self.val = np.ones(100)
        self.result = 0.
    def sum(self):
        self.result = np.sum(self.val)

spec1 = [('ListA',  nb.types.List(First.class_type.instance_type, reflected=True))]

@nb.jitclass(spec1)
class Combined:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ListA = [First(), First()] 
    def sum(self):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            c.sum()
    def getresult(self):
        result = []
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            result.append(c.result)
        return result

C = Combined()
C.sum()
result = C.getresult()
print(result)
```

produces the output: `[100.0, 100.0]`.

### Intermezzo: Does it make sense to use `jitclass` here?

However something to keep in mind here is that normal Python classes will probably be faster than the `jitclass`-approach (or as fast):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = 1
        self.val = np.ones(100)
        self.result = 0.
    def sum(self):
        self.result = np.sum(self.val)

class Combined:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ListA = [First(), First()] 
    def sum(self):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            c.sum()
    def getresult(self):
        result = []
        for i, c in enumerate(self.ListA):
            result.append(c.result)
        return result

C = Combined()
C.sum()
C.getresult()
```

That's no problem if this is just for curiosity. But for production I would start with pure Python+NumPy and only apply numba if it's too slow and then only on the parts that are the bottleneck and only if numba is good at optimizing these things (numba is specialized tool at the moment, not a general purpose tool).

### Heterogeneous (mixed-typed) lists with numba?

With numba in no-python (no-object) mode you need homogeneous lists. As far as I know numba 0.46 doesn't support lists containing different kinds of objects in jitclasses or nopython-jit methods. That means you cannot have one list containing `First` and `Second` instances.

So this cannot work:

```
self.List.append(First())
self.List.append(Second())
```

From the [numba docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.46.0/reference/pysupported.html#list):

> Creating and returning lists from JIT-compiled functions is supported, as well as all methods and operations. **Lists must be strictly homogeneous: Numba will reject any list containing objects of different types, even if the types are compatible** [...]

Comment: Nice. I was close :)

Comment: When you're talking about homogeneous lists. Does that mean that I cannot have a list of lists with different size? like for a list of int lists: [ [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3] ]

Comment: @ymmx Lists of lists is a bit tricky with numba but generally they are supported provided that each list inside your list contains the same element (the size doesn't matter). In your case that's true because each sub-list contains only integers. However passing this list-of-lists to a numba function doesn't work at the moment (numba errors with a message that it cannot determine the type of a reflected list of reflected lists ...). However I wonder why you would use a list-of-lists with numba. numba isn't particularly better with lists than Python.