# Numba - using a jitclass in a jitclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I have a `numba.experimental.jitclass` and I want to pass it a lot of parameters. using a `dataclass` is not supported in `numba`, so I defined my own parameters class.

I try to pass the parameters class to the `jitclass`, but I get an error that the parameters class isn't defined.

When I remove the import of `annotations` it works fine.

Code:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import numpy as np
from numba import float64
from numba.experimental import jitclass


@jitclass
class Parameters:
    p1: int
    p2: int
    p3: int
    p4: int
    p5: int
    p6: int
    p7: int
    p8: int

    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8):
        self.p1: int = p1
        self.p2: int = p2
        self.p3: int = p3
        self.p4: int = p4
        self.p5: int = p5
        self.p6: int = p6
        self.p7: int = p7
        self.p8: int = p8


@jitclass([('table', float64[:, :])])
class MyClass:
    params: Parameters
    table: np.ndarray

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        self.table = np.zeros((params.p7, params.p8))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.table}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my = MyClass(Parameters(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
    print(my.table)
```

The error:

```
NameError: name 'Parameters' is not defined
```

Works when removing the line:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

1. Can anyone explain why removing the import of annotations solves it?
2. Is there any risk removing the import of annotations in this case?
3. Is this way to use `jitclass` in a `jitclass` correct?

I'm aware of the [solution of using `deffered_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682260/how-to-nest-numba-jitclass), but this doesn't work with the import of annotations also.